# React Redux: How to call multiple dependent actions in sequence

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to chain two calls in a single action using a thunk, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. I need the ID value from the first action to call the second one.

Actions look like this:

```
export const getParentRecords = filterId => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        let headers = {
            filter_id: filterId
        };
        const request = axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: `https://myapi.com/v1/parent-records`,
            headers: headers
        });
        dispatch({
            type: GET_PARENT_RECORDS,
            payload: request
        });
    };
};

export const getChildRecords = (parentId = null) => {
    let url = `https://myapi.com/v1/child-records`;
    if (parentId) {
        url = `https://myapi.com/v1/child-records/?parent_id=${parentId}`;
    }
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        let headers = {
            //etc...
        };
        const request = axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: url,
            headers: headers
        });
        dispatch({
            type: GET_CHILD_RECORDS,
            payload: request
        });
    };
};

export const getAllRecords = filterId => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch(getParentRecords(filterId);
        let { parentRecords } = getState();
        let defaultParent = parentRecords.filter(p => p.is_default === true)[0];
        dispatch(getChildRecords(defaultParent.parent_id));
    };
};
```

In calling component:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        parentRecords: state.parentRecords,
        childRecords: state.childRecords
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getAllRecords })(MyComponent);
```

Problem is; dispatching the first action doesn't seem to be doing anything. When I call getState() afterwards, the data isn't there. The parentRecords variable in getAllRecords is always empty.

I'm really not sure what to do with this. Pretty common scenario but haven't found a way through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not interested in introducing yet another framework for something so simple. After the commute home, an idea struck me. Please let me know the pros/cons.

A new getAllRecords function:

```
export const getAllRecords = filterId => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        let headers = {
            // etc...
        };
        const request = axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: `https://myapi.com/v1/parent-records`,
            headers: headers
        });
        request.then(result => {
            if (result.status === 200) {
                let parentRecords = result.data.payload;
                let defaultParent = parentRecords.filter(p => p.is_default === true)[0];
                dispatch({
                    type: GET_PARENT_RECORDS,
                    payload: parentRecords
                });
                dispatch(getChildRecords(defaultParent.parent_id));
            }
        });
    };
};
```

This seems to get me everything I need. Gets parent record(s) by executing the promise, dispatches parent and child results.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use another library for side-effects handling, like `redux-saga` or `redux-observable`, since `redux-thunk` is very primitive.

Redux-saga is generator-based and imperative.
Redux-observable is RxJS-based and declarative.
So choose whatever you like more.

https://redux-saga.js.org/

https://redux-observable.js.org/

---

Each asynchronous action should have three action types, eg: `GET_CHILD_RECORDS`, `GET_CHILD_RECORDS_SUCCESS` and `GET_CHILD_RECORDS_FAILURE`.

Using redux-saga it will look like this:

Action creators:

```
const getChildRecords = (parentId = null) => ({
  type: GET_PARENT_RECORDS,
  payload: parentId
});
```

Then you can handle this action in saga generator:

```
function rootSaga*() {
  yield takeLatest(GET_PARENT_RECORDS, onGetParentRecords);
  yield takeLatest(GET_PARENT_RECORDS_SUCCESS, onGetChildRecords);
}

function onGetParentRecords*({ payload: parentId }) {
  try {
    const parentRecords = yield call(apiCallFunctionHere, parentId);
    yield put({
      type: GET_PARENT_RECORDS_SUCCESS,
      payload: parentRecords
    });
  } catch(error) {
    yield put({
      type: GET_PARENT_RECORDS_FAILURE,
      error
    });
  }
}

function onGetChildRecords*({ payload: parentRecords }) {
  const defaultParent = parentRecords.filter(p => p.is_default === true)[0];
  try {
    const childRecords = call(apiFunctionToFetchChildRecords, defaultParent);
    yield put({
      type: GET_CHILDREN_RECORDS_SUCCESS,
      payload: parentRecords
    });
  } catch(error) {
    yield put({
      type: GET_CHILDREN_RECORDS_FAILURE,
      error
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting...I've seen these recommended elsewhere but would like to avoid another framework for something so simple. Check out the answer I posted. I only have a year or so of React & Redux so feedback is helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Yuriy Yakym, I have the same requirement as @Tsar Bomba described and it works perfectly in redux-saga as you explained